# PhoneGap FileTransfer.upload params no longer posting

Tags: file-upload, cordova, file-transfer

I just upgraded from Cordova (PhoneGap) 1.5 to 1.9 today and suddenly my FileTransfer params stopped posting.  I can tell because I have the server side debugging the $_POST parameters, and they are now blank.  Here is the code being run:

```
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode=false;

    var params = new Object();
    params.client_token = "This will not make it across, sadly...";  

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    rs = ft.upload(imageURI, "http://www.mysite.com/api/uploadimage", 
        function() { alert('Yay!'); }, 
        function() { alert('Fail happens..'); }, options, true);
```

Has this happened to anyone else?  Maybe there's a new setting that has to be set?

**UPDATE:**

Just to make sure it wasn't CodeIgniter causing server side issues, I now have the above code posting to echo.php, which simply does "print var_dump($_REQUEST);".  Still no results.  I was able to cheat and throw the client token on the URL as a $_GET parameter, but it seems a shame to hack the server side because the client side changed.

Comment: the above code works fine for me in cordova 1.9 and nodejs server, where `client_token` is part of the form-data in POST request.

Comment: That's bizarre.  Thanks for checking.  Since I'm only using the code in one spot I've switch it to a GET.  I guess I'll hook up http://www.charlesproxy.com/ to my phone and debug what is actually being transferred.

Comment: This code is working for me too ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with the iOS Cordova 1.9.  I found and fixed the bug in the framework code, you can download my fork of Cordova and use the newly patched /dist/Cordova-1.9.0.dmg from it: https://github.com/eschultz/incubator-cordova-ios/

At a quick glance the Android Cordova 1.9 code looked fine.  I submitted my changes to Apache to include the fix in their next release.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Eric!  I appreciate you confirming that at least I'm not crazy.  :)  I've already hacked my API to use a GET parameter, but I'll keep an eye out for the fix in the next Cordova.  You rock!

Comment: @Anthony I had the exact same issue upgrading. Good catch, Eric. Here is the JIRA I opened on it the other day: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1015

Comment: I'm seeing similar misbehaviour with Cordova 2.0. Not sure if this a new bug or the same one resurfacing, but FileTransfer under some circumstances seems to be broken (sending back negative file sizes and such).

Comment: P.S.: manually clearing my app's cache seems to have (at least temporarily) fixed the problem... pretty sure it's not just me though. We had several other people report the same thing. Sounds like it might have something to do with temporary photo/file storage rather than FileTransfer though.